# can I write two similar restful web service

Tags: spring-mvc

this question is asked in an interview.
Can we implement two similar endpoints with same uri and same method type? If yes, how does dispatcherservlet identifies the endpoint? If not, what exception we will get?

Ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity test(){
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity test1(){
}
```

Comment: Just test it, and you will have the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If you try, you will get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'testController' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.TestController.test1()
to {[/test],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'testController' bean method
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.TestController.test() mapped.
```